# How can read information and put this information in array of object

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have have a file, `file.txt` like

```
7 10 5  
ADD_FLIGHT SV221 Jeddah NewYork 30 7000  
ADD_FLIGHT SV223 Jeddah London 30 4000  
ADD_FLIGHT SV225 Jeddah Paris 30 3500  
ADD_FLIGHT SV227 Jeddah Cairo 30 2000  
ADD_PASS Mohammed Ali 33 M 0555788778  
ADD_PASS Sara Maghrabi 30 F 0555111111  
ADD_PASS Hani Ali 20 M 0555223344  
ADD_PASS Mohammed Hafeth 33 M 0555889876  
ADD_PASS Ahmad Sami 44 M 0555768768  
ADD_FLIGHT SV332 Jeddah Riyadh 20 500  
ADD_FLIGHT SV334 Jeddah Dammam 20 600  
ADD_FLIGHT SV367 Jeddah Dubai 25 2000  
ADD_PASS Salwa Ali 33 F 0555765672  
ADD_PASS Faisal Amri 20 M 0555111111  
ADD_PASS Mona Saleem 33 F 0555222112  
ADD_PASS Ali Ali 33 M 0555743344  
ADD_PASS Marwa Ahmad 33 F 0555545855
```

I want to put information after the `ADD_FLIGHT` in an array of objects

My code is not correct, because `setTotalSeats` does not work with string.

How can I correct the code and put the flight information in an array of objects?

```
public static void inputFlight (Flight tempFlight  ) throws IOException{
     FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
     DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
     BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
     String strLine;
     while ((strLine = br2.readLine()) != null) {
      if(strLine.contains("ADD_FLIGHT")){
             tempFlight.setFlightCode(strLine.replace("ADD_FLIGHT",""));  
                    tempFlight.setCityFrom(strLine.replace("ADD_PASS",""));
    tempFlight.setCityTo(strLine.replace("ADD_PASS",""));
    tempFlight.setTotalSeats(strLine.replace("ADD_PASS",""));
```

Comment: can you please clarify "I want Makes information after ADD_FLIGHT statement in array of object if find ADD_FLIGHT"?

Comment: ? Is the problem now clear

Comment: how about now is mine version better? I think. **btw, can you close your if statement**

Comment: No, it's still not clear. You need to explain what the problem with `settotalSeats()` is. For that you need to show us its definition. You really show every piece of code that is referenced from this code (the methods, where they are defined, and so on). Also, explain the format of the file, and what you want there to be in your array.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your `while` loop to look something like this:

```
while ((strLine = br2.readLine()) != null) {
    if(strLine.contains("ADD_FLIGHT")){
        String[] flightInfo = strLine.split(" ");
        //first line of your example would be: {0=ADD_FLIGHT, 1=SV221, 2=Jeddah, 3=NewYork, 4=30, 5=7000}
        String flightCode = flightInfo[1];
        String cityFrom = flightInfo[2];
        String cityTo = flightInfo[3];
        int totalSeats = Integer.parseInt(flightInfo[4]);
    }
}
```

Now you can use the contents of each variable to do whatever it is that you're trying to do.